# How to replace a substring within a StringBuilder if the substring is greater than x?

Tags: c#, html, css, regex, ckeditor

I have a stringbuilder(sb) that is sb.Appending a long string of HTML(from a CKEditor textbox).

My problem is that CSS !important tags are not working for a table that is being created within the CKEditor.

I am trying to set a maximum width for a table(if one is created) and edit the tables width value only if it exceeds a certain amount. IE width:900px exceeds 200px so replace the value with a width:200px value before inserting it into stringbuilder
Example:

```
<style>
.div table{width:200px; !Important}
</style>

<p>"Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing 
    elit, sed do eiusmod 
    tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua."</p>

    <p>de Finibus Bonorum et Malorum", written by Cicero in 45 BC</p>

        <p>"Sed ut perspiciatis unde omnis iste natus error sit voluptatem 
            accusantium doloremque laudantium, totam"</p>

        <p> </p>

        <table border="1" cellpadding="1" cellspacing="1" style="height:55px; width:900px">
            <tbody>
                <tr>
                    <td> </td>
                    <td>Value</td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td>Example</td>
                    <td>50</td>
                </tr>
            </tbody>
        </table>

        <p> </p>

        <p>1914 translation by H. Rackham</p>

        <p>"But I must explain to you how all this mistaken idea of denouncing pleasure and praising pain was born and I will give you a complete account of the system."</p>
```

I've also tried some Regex approaches but because I'm not very familiar with it I would rather not use Regex.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The s.some_long_string was the string of html from the question above.

```
string TempString = s.some_long_string;    
string replace;
```

This finds the part of the string that starts with "width:", has any number and/or sequence of characters,and then ends with "px".

```
MatchCollection matchlist = Regex.Matches(s.some_long_string, "width:(.*)px");
```

This collects all the instances where "width:" pops up.

```
var list = matchlist.Cast<Match>().Select(match => match.Value).ToList();

foreach (var v in list)
{
    replace = v;
```

This separates the number from the rest of the string

```
    var resultString = Regex.Match(v, @"\d+").Value;

    if (Convert.ToInt32(resultString) > 745)
    {
        TempString = TempString.Replace(replace, "width:745px");
        s.some_long_string = TempString;
    }
}
```